# Pyspark to_timestamp date format parsing error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, to-timestamp

In my pyspark dataframe, there is a column `CallDate` with datatype as `string` containing the values shown below:

```
2008-04-01T00:00:00
2008-04-01T00:00:00
2008-04-01T00:00:00
2008-04-01T00:00:00
2008-04-01T00:00:00
2008-04-01T00:00:00
```

I am trying to convert this columns from datatype `string` to `timestamp` using `pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp()`.

When I am running this code:

```
df.withColumn('IncidentDate', to_timestamp(col('CallDate'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')).select('CallDate', 'IncidentDate').show()
```

... I am getting this output:

```
+-------------------+------------+
|           CallDate|IncidentDate|
+-------------------+------------+
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|        NULL|
```

I believe the `NULL` values are due to the fact that the format specified for the date is not consistent with the actual date string, and since no match is found, the `NULL` values are returned.

But when I run this code:

```
df.withColumn('IncidentDate', to_timestamp(col('CallDate'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')).select('CallDate', 'IncidentDate').show()
```

I am getting an error saying that

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: [INCONSISTENT_BEHAVIOR_CROSS_VERSION.PARSE_DATETIME_BY_NEW_PARSER] You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0:
Fail to parse '2008-04-01T00:00:00' in the new parser. You can set "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy" to "LEGACY" to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to "CORRECTED" and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
```

I know the correct parse format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` as shown below:

```
df.withColumn('IncidentDate', to_timestamp(col('CallDate'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")).select('CallDate', 'IncidentDate').show()
```

But my question is why is it that when I give the date parse format as `yyyy/MM/dd`, Spark returns `NULL` values but when I give it as `yyyy-MM-dd`, it is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you use format `yyyy/MM/dd`, both old and new datetime parsers are unable to parse the input, so the result would be NULL in both cases regardless of Spark (and its parser) version. However, with `yyyy-MM-dd` format the old parser, being more lenient, returns a valid value while the new one still fails and returns NULL. Spark detects such cases through internal check, and creates and throws a very special `SparkUpgradeException` with a very specific message to attract your attention to the potential regression issue. More about new parsing logic in Spark 3.x, and the effects of `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` config can be found in [Spark Migration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#query-engine) and/or source code.

Answer (score 0):

`to_timestamp` is able to parse your strings without specifying any pattern :

```
df.withColumn("IncidentDate", to_timestamp(col("CallDate")))
    .select("CallDate", "IncidentDate")
    .show();
+-------------------+-------------------+
|           CallDate|       IncidentDate|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2008-04-01T00:00:00|2008-04-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. But my question is regarding the odd behavior of `to_timestamp()` where on one hand it returns NULL values with date parse string as `yyyy/MM/dd`, but on the other hand when I use the format `yyyy-MM-dd` it is throwing an error.